# float right element outside of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div and three children. i want one to float left of parent, one to be in exact center of parent and one to float right of parent. but the floated right element has gone outside of the parent div. its not because of lack of space.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x8Dm/7/)

```css
#boards {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#boards p {
  font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
  color: rgba(160, 224, 247, 1);
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.board_items {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#board_items_container {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: relative;
}
#board1 {
  float: left;
  padding: relative;
}
#board2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: relative;
}
#board3 {
  float: right;
  padding: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="boards">
  <p>TOP BOARDS</p>
  <div id="board_items_container">
    <div id="board1" class="board_items">
    </div>
    <div id="board2" class="board_items">
    </div>
    <div id="board3" class="board_items">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `padding: relative;` do? I've never seen before. Did you mean `position: relative;`?

Comment: padding: relative isnt valid

Comment: opps, my bad. auto complete in my sublime is broke :P

Comment: you could simply use `display: inline-block;` for all three `div` tags to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your HTML, move the right-floated element before the element you want it to float around:

```
<div id="boards">
  <p>TOP BOARDS</p>
  <div id="board_items_container">
    <div id="board1" class="board_items"> <!-- float: left -->
    </div>
    <div id="board3" class="board_items"> <!-- float: right -->
    </div>
    <div id="board2" class="board_items"> <!-- not floated -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you could give an explanation what went wrong, why it worked when i moved the third element above??

Comment: Since `board2` is a block-level element, it fills all the available horizontal space. If `board3` comes after it, it must be on the next line. If it's placed before, it can be on the same line, and that space is no longer available to `board2`.

Comment: @RiverCRPhoenix - when you give margin-left/right:auto.. it takes up the whole space of the parent div. so when the float right elements comes into picture, it has no place to go but down. so by moving the right block up, you make the right part render first

Comment: i got another doubt, when i give margin-left/right auto, why is element's left margin is from the parent and not from end of first/sibling-before, and margin right affects the next/sibling-after.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. You should probably post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css code:

```
#board1 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#board2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#board3 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```